# dropdown-menu and drop-down list width is not perfectly align

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am not sure why my dropdown-menu, and my drop-down list width is not perfectly align. I set both of their width to be: `width:300px;`

It looks like this right now :

[image]

Here is what I have in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/1tsad5vd/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `.dropdown` is inside the container `#dd`, its initial x-axis wont be the same as the parent, if the parent has any of the css layout enhancement applied which effect its width, like `border` or `padding` etc.

To solve this, you shall have to negate the effect of that `padding` or `border`, by applying a respective negative starting point on x-axis.

so just make the following change to your code.

```
.wrapper-dropdown-1 .dropdown {
   position: absolute;
   top: 100%;
   left: -1px; /* <--- This is the change */
   right: 0;
   background: white;
   list-style: none;
   font-weight: normal;
   opacity: 0;
   pointer-events: none;
   width: 300px;
   border-right: 1px solid black;
   border-bottom: 1px solid black;
   border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: If my answer has healped, please make it the accepted answer.

Comment: You deserve it. Thanks again. :D

Answer (score 1):

If you add `left: -1px;` to your `.wrapper-dropdown-1 .dropdown` style it works the like it should. See bellow the added style rule

```css
.wrapper-dropdown-1 .dropdown {
    
    /* Size & position */
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: -1px;
    right: 0;
```